# Navigation on Raspberry Pi via Kivy

Tags: python, navigation, gps, raspberry-pi, kivy

I am working on a car project using Raspberry Pi with Raspbian Jessie and Kivy installed. I also have the gps module by adafruit and finally made it to work. I want to install a navigation system (like this one http://raspberrypi.link-tech.de/doku.php?id=navitnavigation ) but I want to run tha navit program via a kivy app.

Basically my goal is to have a kivy app that contains buttons and when I press the button "navit" then the navigation app pops up. Is that possible?

Also, is there a way to make the Raspberry boot directly into an app (python)?

Thanks in advance! (Sorry if my English bad. Not my native language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/05/how-to-autostart-apps-in-rasbian-lxde-desktop/) you can find a good explanation on how to add your kivy application to the autostart items of the Raspberry Pi standard desktop. If you want the autostart for every user you can do as described:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

and add (assuming you are using Python 2)

```
@/usr/bin/python /path/to/your/kivy/main.py
```

For the navigation app popup:
Bind a python handler method to the navit-button and use the [subproces.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) method to start the existing navit application.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That was very helpful. Also Is there a way to avoid the standard LXDE at all? Or is it possible to  just boot into the app in full screen so the desktop be hidden?

Comment: You can set the kivy application to fullscreen (see fullscreen in the graphics section here: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html#available-configuration-tokens). That should hide the desktop below.

Comment: With Kivy you don't actually even need to start X (and LXDE), and will also get better performance if you don't.

Comment: @inclement Awesome. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Build kivy with the rpi-specific window backend. I thought it used it automatically on rpi if possible, but if not there'll probably be an env var for it.